# Add two different index.html in angular.cli.json

Tags: html, angular5

I have to add two index.html for prod and dev, I'm using angular5 project need to add under angular.cli.json

where and how to add them?

I have tried with configuration but this says above version 6

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you add a piece of code and/or a directory structure showing us how you currently dispatched things?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate section where you can configure this.

[angular documentation for inputs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#index-configuration)

> input - The path of a file to use for the application's generated HTML index.

Here are additional resources for you to refer.

1. [resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324204/how-to-replace-index-html-in-angular-8-3-depending-on-environment) Answer from frido

Comment: Do I need to repeat the SO rule that I quoted?